# Seaborn FacetGrid: make labels visible in each subplot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart, facet-grid

I have built a Seaborn plot with the below data

[image]

I made the below code to show the FacetGrid

```
  def facetGridSales():
    grouped_sales_data=pd.read_excel("Random Sales Data.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
    g=sns.FacetGrid(data=grouped_sales_data,col='Location',col_wrap=4)
    g.map(sns.barplot,'Item','Total Sale Amount',order=['Junk','Stuff','Widgets','Things'])
    plt.savefig('CustomFacetGrid.jpg')
```

I have used col_wrap=4 to give 4 subplots in each line.
[image]

My issue is that the labels ('Junk','Stuff','Widgets','Things) are not visible for the first row of subplots. Is there a way to increase the space between the rows of FacetGrid to make the first row labels visible ?

Comment: You should be using `sns.catplot` with `kind='ba'` not mapping onto a FacetGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unshare the x-axis, it will be displayed on each of them.

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(data=df,col='Location',col_wrap=4, sharex=False)
```

[image]